# A word for someone who loves to travel with no plans but has an objective

Tags: single-word-requests

I am a photographer and love to go out everyday, but I have no specific place in mind. But, I know I have to be out somewhere to take landscape photos (focus). So, I am looking for a word to describe myself like - Nomad, Wanderer, etc But, I feel none of these describe my spontaneous nature.

Only word closest to what I want is a French word called
[Dérive](https://www.twowanderingsoles.com/blog/14-awesome-travel-words-you-have-never-heard):

> Definition: A spontaneous journey where the traveler lets the spirit of the landscape and architecture move them.

Is there an English word that is close to this french word?

Comment: 5 Untranslatable Words That Perfectly Describe The Beauty Of Traveling : https://thoughtcatalog.com/bianca-sparacino/2015/06/5-untranslatable-words-that-perfectly-describe-the-beauty-of-traveling/

Comment: Adventurer. Outdoorsy, Frequent Flyer.